# Convert static image to Base64 in ReactNative

Tags: android, ios, react-native, base64, react-image

I have static image which i need to convert in `Base64` and then send it to Android/iOS native code.

If i select an image from file i am able to send it to native code and convert that to `Base64`.

But what if i have static image and then send it to native code.

```
<Image source={require('./img/icon.png')}/>
```

I want `icon.png` to be sent in Android/iOS native module.

I have done native coding, it is something like this

```
@ReactMethod
public void filterBase64(String base64, Callback stringCallback) {

}
```

But stucked at how to send `Base64`

I have checked [react-native-image-to-base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-to-base64) but not able to get solution, when i use

```
NativeModules.RNImageToBase64.getBase64String(uri, (err, base64) => {
    // Do something with the base64 string 
})
```

It shows error `undefined is not an object`

Comment: I've used: https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob

Comment: Did you try rebuilding after installing react-native-image-to-base64 ? I got the same error because i hadn't rebuilt it

Answer (score 3):

With the help of [RNFS](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs) plugin you can access React Native assets and convert them to Base64.

```
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs')
base64data = await RNFS.readFile('./img/icon.png', 'base64').then();
console.log(base64data);
```

Comment: its shows `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './img/android.png'` even though path is correct

Comment: Confirm your directory using `process.cwd()`

Comment: It is same, even i have used same path in `<Image>` and it is showing that image.

Comment: Have you given read & write permissions in your manifest file ?  

Like this : `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />`


Also if API version is > Android L Please give run time permissions .

Comment: Hi @RaviRupareliya: The path "./img/android.png" may lack of something, so the image cannot be found. In my case, when I use the image path "./../../../../images/dialog/cross.png", the same error appear. Then I use "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/IMG_20171206_104414.jpg" (local image file), everything work like a charm with the same code. Hope it may help you

Comment: @RaviRupareliya any luck on this? am trying to access images in assets folder its giving me `Error: ENOENT` . Did u succeed in this ?

Comment: For converting to base 64, you must read from the file.. Static image won't work.